How to format a specific address in Chinese?
How to format this address? I want to sent package and not sure what is street, what is town…

zhang yan 18790555906 China Guangdong Province Dongguan Shatian Town
shan bian lu bin hai ming zhu 4dong504 CN 523000 Dongguan Guangdong
Province


It seems there's a lot of packages to this region: e.g. for the questions I need help with a chinese address, Assistance with Chinese address needed, it's the same city.

Seems like this,
Nation: China,
Province: Guangdong,
City: Dongguan,
Town: Shatian,
Road/Street: Shan bian lu,
building: Bin hai ming zhu 4-504,
ZIP Code: 523000.
In chinese:
广东省东莞市沙田镇山边路滨海明珠4栋504 邮编：523000

You are right.  If mailing from somewhere outside of china, including the recipients name and phone number is a must in case customs//mailman needs to call them at any point.

If it's not clear: zhang yan 18790555906 is the name and phone number.  The name is most likely written 张艳 in Chinese.

If you don't know the Chinese, you can just write pure english on the envelope .
or both
--
 _Your Address_



張艷 小姐 收



中華人民共和國 廣東省 東莞市 沙田鎮 山邊路 濱海明珠 4棟 504號 
ZIP code: 523000
Tel: (+86)18790555906 


It is a very simple matter. I remember that back in 1990s when there was no computer service widely available we asked the addressee in China to send us his address written on paper in Chinese or biligual, so that we could cut it out and paste on the envelope, without even knowing what the address really meant. And now you can do the same and it is much easier, you can ask her to send you the word document on which her address is given and then print it out.
